# Insert Data To Another Table Using SQL Server Trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have created two tables called `enquiry_master` and `enquiry_master_hist`..

I'm updating column `refference_no` on table `enquiry_master` using SQL server Trigger..

Now I want to insert `enquiry_master_hist` with same data what was inserted to `enquiry_master`. All fine data are inserting but that updated column only inserting with old data...

There is any way to get updated data in SQL Server trigger??? This is code

```
UPDATE enquiry_master
SET    enquiry_master.reference_no = pass.RandomPassword
FROM   #Users tmp
CROSS APPLY       dbo.GeneratePassword_Real(CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(@RefferenceNOLength)) pass
WHERE  enquiry_master.enquiry_id = @EnquiryId;
DECLARE @InsertedID AS INT;
select @EnquiryId = i.enquiry_id from inserted i;
select @UpdatedRefference = i.reference_no from inserted i;

SET IDENTITY_INSERT enquiry_master_hist ON
INSERT INTO enquiry_master_hist([enquiry_id],
[enquiry_source_id],
[reference_no],
[assigned_staff_no],
[emp_id],
[status_id],
[remarks],
[enquiry_date_time],
[departing_from],
[travelling_to],
[departing_date],
[returning_date],
[hotel_name],
[airline],
[flight_class],
[no_of_adult_passangers],
[no_of_child_passangers],
[no_of_infant_passangers],
[taxes],
[from_price],
[total_price],
[name],
[home_office_no],
[mobile_no],
[prefered_callback_time],
[email],
[additional_comments],
[from_website],
[from_campaign],
[enquiry_type_id],
[type_of_group],
[budget],
[supplier],
[trip_code],
[trip_name],
[no_of_countries],
[no_of_days],
[countries],
[deal_reference_no],
[how_did_know],
[no_of_rooms],
[bedding],
[room_views],
[board_basis],
[system_date],
[system_time]
)
VALUES(
@EnquiryId,
@EnquirySourceId,
@UpdatedRefference,
@AssignedStaffNo,
@EmpId,@StatusId,
@Remarks,
@EnquiryDatetime,
@DepartingFrom,
@TravellingTo,
@DepartingDate,
@ReturningDate,
@HotelName,
@Airline,
@FlightClass,
@NoOfAdults,
@NoOfChild,
@NoOfInfant,
@Taxes,
@FromPrice,
@TotalPrice,
@Name,
@HomeofficeNo,
@MobileNo,
@PreferedCallbackTime,
@Email,
@AdditionalComments,
@FromWebsite,
@FromCompaign,
@EnquiryTypeId,
@TypeOfGroup,
@Budget,
@Supplier,
@TripCode,
@TripName,
@NoOfCountries,
@NoOfDays,
@Countries,
@DealRefferenceNo,
@HowDidknow,
@NoOfRooms,
@Bedding,
@RoomViews,
@BoardBasis,
@SystemDate,
@SystemTime)

SET IDENTITY_INSERT enquiry_master_hist OFF
END
```

**strong text**

Answer (score 0):

You can not get any updated dynamic table. SQL allows only inserted and deleted. In case of Update command, previous data is stored in the deleted dynamic table, and new values are stored in the inserted dynamic table.

Comment: Ok thanks for your reply Mike Clark, Can you give me an example to get that data please???

Comment: For the "previous" data...select * from deleted. For the new values...select * from inserted. And make sure you stop using scalar variables all over your trigger. Whatever you do needs to be set based because triggers fire once per operation and the virtual tables can contain multiple rows.

Comment: guys I found a way to do this when i'm Updating I'm setting a variable to store that value and using in Insert query..that is working for me